# Can tcolorbox work with a left-side wrapfigure?

Tags: tcolorbox, wrapfigure

It seems that tcolorboxes work fine with wrapfigures as long as the wrapfigure is on the right side of the page. However, if I change the wrapfigure `R` option to `L`, then the tcolorbox continues to align at the left edge. What's the best workaround?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}[7]{L}{5cm}
  \tcbincludepdf[scale=1,size=tight,opacityframe=0]{example-image.pdf}
\end{wrapfigure}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. 
\begin{tcolorbox}
  Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo.
\end{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`wrapfigure` is nothing that works out of the box, it requires manual adjustment, as well as the surrounding boxes besides the `wrapfigure`. I suggest to use `left skip=5.5cm` and a narrower `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}[7]{L}{5cm}
  \tcbincludepdf[scale=1,size=tight,opacityframe=0]{example-image.pdf}
\end{wrapfigure}%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. 
\begin{tcolorbox}[left skip=5.5cm,width=11cm]
  Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo.
\end{tcolorbox}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. 

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `\begin{tcolorbox}[enlarge left by =\csname @totalleftmargin\endcsname]`, then you don't have to guess (this doesn't work if the tcolorbox is the first thing beside the wrapfigure).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks, I will change later on, for now I am occupied with other issues regarding my own code. `enlarge left by` is one of the 5000 keys of `tcolorbox` which are used pretty often, I assume? ;-)

Answer (score 6):

You can easily obtain what you want with the `insbox` plain TeX macro package. It defines an `\InsertBoxL` command (also `\InsertBoxR` and `\InsertBoxC`)  to insert objects in a paragraph, with two mandatory arguments: the number of unshortened lines before insertion of the object, and this object. In addition an optional argument can be used: the number of supplementary shortened lines, in case TeX doesn't calculate the right number of shorter lines.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\input{insbox.tex}

\begin{document}

\InsertBoxL{0}{\includegraphics[width = 5cm]{example-image.pdf}}[1]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.
\begin{tcolorbox}[width = \dimexpr\linewidth-5.2cm]
  Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo.
\end{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]